# getting xpath for parent

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am new to xpath, I have a html structure like this:

```
 <div _ngcontent-c7="" class="new-dash hvr-fade ng-star-inserted" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="//service-aaaa" id="app109">
   <h5 _ngcontent-c7="" class="parent-highlight">
      <a _ngcontent-c7="" class="parent-highlight">
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
            }--><br _ngcontent-c7="">
      </a>
      <img _ngcontent-c7="" alt="AppIcon" class="icon-active" width="65px" id="appIcon10" src="../assets/images/service_category_active.svg">
      <h5 _ngcontent-c7="" class="parent-highlight top-20 new-label" id="appNameText10">Service1234</h5>
   </h5>
</div>
```

I want to select parent div which has **h5.text=Service1234**

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//h5[text()="Service1234"]/ancestor::div[1]
```

Reads: find that "h5" element, find all its ancestor "div"-s in reverse order (closest first), and return the first one.

Answer (score 1):

As said, need to find location of h5 containing text Service1234 and move up to get required div.

you can also try like

```
 //h5[contains(text(),'Service1234')]/parent::h5/parent::div
```

see this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: A friendly critique :) - this depends on the structure of the HTML, if there's an intermediate node between the "div" and the "h5" (either of the 2 "h5"s), it won't match. And as a node can have only one parent, limiting its name is redundant - this expression has the same result: `//h5[text()="Service1234"]/../..`

Comment: @TodorMinakov thanks you, just tried as per provided html code